# Android - How can I link my free app to the Pro version

Tags: android, google-play

How can I link my free android application to the "paid" version so a user of the free one can instantly click on the link and be taken to the android market page for the full version.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Create a view somewhere that will advertise your Pro version.  Perhaps it's an ImageView, perhaps it's a Button or a link, whatever it might be, just make sure it's something the user can click.

Then do the following:

```
view.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View v) {
        startActivity( new Intent( Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://search?q=pname:XXX") ) );
    }
}
```

... where XXX is the package name for your Pro application, as specified in your AndroidManifest.xml.

When the user clicks the view, Android will launch your Pro application's page on the market.

Comment: I'd suggest to use `market://details?id=<packagename>` as it will open the app page straight. More info: http://developer.android.com/intl/de/guide/publishing/publishing.html

Answer (score 2):

I would say for exposure purposes, why not have a small, i mean very small, advertisement for your paid app? Or have a button to select "Get full version". This way if your "free" app is linked to your "paid" application you might lose an audience.